# Encontrar el carácter * y sustituirlo con <b> en Mysql 5

Tags: mysql, regex

Deseo encontrar el carácter `*` en un campo de texto, pero debe ubicar donde tenga el `*` seguido de alguna letra y sustituirlo con `<b>`, y el caso contrario donde tenga una letra seguido de un `*`, y sustituirlo con `</b>`. Debo tomar en consideración los siguientes casos,

Ejemplo:

1. `hola *buenos dias* como estas`  ----> `hola <b>buenos dias</b> como estas`
2. `hola *buenos* *dias* como estas`  ----> `hola <b>buenos</b> <b>dias</b> como estas`
3. `hola *bueno* dias como * estas`   ----> `hola <b>buenos</b> dias como * estas`

He leído sobre REGEXP pero aun no doy con la solución. Tengo la versión 5 de MySQL no puedo usar REGEXP_REPLACE.

Comment: Este [modulo](https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp) externo implementa la función REGEXP_REPLACE para la versión 5 de mysql. Puedes darle una mirada.

Comment: Debes agregar esa funcionalidad.